# Can someone tell me why am i getting this error even though the arguments are correct?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is the .h file which i'm trying to submit and the tester is not letting it through because of errors of the same type.

```
#ifndef SICT_ICTCOURSE_H__
#define SICT_ICTCOURSE_H__

#include "Course.h"

namespace sict {
    class ICTCourse : public Course {
    private:
        char computerSystem_[6 + 1];

    public:
        ICTCourse();
        ICTCourse(const char* courseCode, const char* coursetitle, int credits, int studyload, char* computerSystem);

        const char* getComputerSystem() const;
        void setComputerSystem(const char* value);
        void display(ostream&);
    };
}
#endif
```

These are the errors which i do not understand. I've provided all the arguments that are needed.

```
M2CourseTester.cpp: In function âbool isEmptyTest1()â:
M2CourseTester.cpp:19:38: error: no matching function for call to    âsict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char [1], const char [6], int, int)â
M2CourseTester.cpp:19:38: note: candidates are:
ICTCourse.h:20:3: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char*, const char*, int, int, char*)
ICTCourse.h:20:3: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
ICTCourse.h:18:3: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse()
ICTCourse.h:18:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
ICTCourse.h:9:8: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const sict::ICTCourse&)
ICTCourse.h:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
M2CourseTester.cpp: In function âbool isEmptyTest2()â:
M2CourseTester.cpp:25:37: error: no matching function for call to âsict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char [5], const char [1], int, int)â
M2CourseTester.cpp:25:37: note: candidates are:
ICTCourse.h:20:3: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char*, const char*, int, int, char*)
ICTCourse.h:20:3: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
ICTCourse.h:18:3: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse()
ICTCourse.h:18:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
ICTCourse.h:9:8: note: sict::ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const sict::ICTCourse&)  
ICTCourse.h:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
```

This is the ICTCourse.cpp file

```
#include "ICTCourse.h"

namespace sict {
    ICTCourse::ICTCourse():Course() {
        strcpy(computerSystem_, "matrix");
    }

    ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char* courseCode, const char* courseTitle, int credits, int studyLoad, char* computerSystem){
        courseCode_Setter(courseCode);
        courseTitle_Setter(courseTitle);
        credits_Setter(credits);
        studyLoad_Setter(studyLoad);
        strcpy(computerSystem_, computerSystem);
    }

    const char* ICTCourse::getComputerSystem() const{
        return computerSystem_;
    }

    void ICTCourse::setComputerSystem(const char* value){
        strncpy(computerSystem_, value, 6);
    }

    void ICTCourse::display(ostream& pout){

        pout << left << setw(MAX_COURSECODE_LEN) << getCourseCode() << " | " << left << setw(20) << getCourseTitle() << " | " << right << setw(6) << getCredits() << " | " << right << setw(4) << getStudyLoad() << " | " << left << setw(6) << computerSystem_ << " | " << setw(4) <<"  "<< " | ";

    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] needed. It looks like it could be a number of things, such as not providing enough arguments to the constructor.

Comment: What could be causing this error?

Comment: As @AndyG says, you don't provide enough information. What source file are you compiling?

Comment: I can send you the file by email if you want?

Comment: @Akshi: Please read the link I provided. It should be possible to create a small working example that reproduces your problem. Afterwards, paste that small example here on StackOverflow (bonus points if you put it in an online compiler for us to look at)

Comment: The error message states that the constructor arguments used in `M2CourseTester.cpp` don't match the constructor parameters you've defined.  The test expects to be able to create an `ICTCourse` with four arguments, not five.

Comment: Please give an indication of the the actual error in the post title to help attract answerers.

Answer (score 2):

This log says that in the file `M2CourseTester.cpp` On lines 19 and 25 the constructor of class `ICTCourse` is invoked with wrong set of arguments.

There is probably code similar to this:

```
ICTCourse* course = new ICTCourse("", "maths", 1, 1);
```

While the constructor expects 5 parameters:

- `const char* courseCode` - `""` of type `const char [5]`
- `const char* coursetitle` - `"maths"` of type  `const char [1]`
- `int credits` - `1` of type `int`
- `int studyload` - `1` of type `int`
- `char* computerSystem` - missing

You need to provide fifth argument to constructor.

---

UPD.
Following syntax is not a default argument:

```
ICTCourse::ICTCourse()
  :Course() {
    strcpy(computerSystem_, "matrix");
}
```

You can read about default arguments [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)

It would look like this:

```
//ICTCourse.h
...
ICTCourse(const char* courseCode,  
  const char* coursetitle,  
  int credits, 
  int studyload,  
  char* computerSystem = "matrix");
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^ default value here
...
```

```
//ICTCourse.cpp
...
ICTCourse::ICTCourse(const char* courseCode,  
  const char* courseTitle,  
  int credits,  
  int studyLoad,  
  char* computerSystem /* = matrix*/){
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^ no value here
  //                   good practice to keep it as a comment
```

Comment: But i've given a default value for variable computerSystem_

Comment: @Akshi No, you didn't. Default would be `..., char* computerSystem = nullptr);` And you have none of those

Comment: In the constructor i've assigned "matrix" as the default value? Does it take that value?